# JBOSS AS 7.1 MDB deployment fails when run in domain mode (Clustered HornetQ)

Tags: jboss7.x, hornetq

When it is deployed in JBOSS Standalone mode the MDB works. In clustered mode deployment is giving an error

```
 {"JBAS014771: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.deployment.subunit.\"MroExecutorEar.ear\".\"MroExecutor.jar\".component.MroExecutorMDB.CREATEjboss.ra.hornetq-raMissing[jboss.deployment.subunit.\"MroExecutorEar.ear\".\"MroExecutor.jar\".component.MroExecutorMDB.CREATEjboss.ra.hornetq-ra]"]}
```

POM Snapshot

> 

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

   <dependency>
        <groupId>com.nokia.oss</groupId>
        <artifactId>MroCore</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-ejb-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <ejbVersion>3.1</ejbVersion>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <finalName>MroExecutor</finalName>
</build>
```

Code Snapshot

```
@MessageDriven(
    activationConfig = { 
            @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue"),
            @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destination", propertyValue = "jms/queue/MROQueue")
    })
```

public class MroExecutorMDB implements MessageListener{

JBOSS AS 7.1.1 Final running in two nodes as Master Slave configuraion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root cause of the problem is that in JBoss AS 7.1.1 in domain mode you need to change the socket binding in the server group to full-ha-sockets

```
<server-group name="other-server-group" profile="full-ha">
                   <jvm name="default">
                       <heap size="64m" max-size="512m"/>
                   </jvm>
                   <socket-binding-group ref="full-ha-sockets"/>
```

Here is the code and configuration for JBoss and HornetQ clustering - http://alexpunnen.blogspot.in/2014/09/jboss-as-711-and-hornetq-clustering-in.html